# Access VBA. Detect if recordset entry will give overflow

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

I have the following code where I loop through a recordset generated by a query, and sometimes, a couple of the lines in the query will return (0/0). When looping through the recordset to write out to excel, if the line in the query did return (0/0), I receive an overflow error when trying to access it. I am trying to catch this overflow error, and assign the string "0%" to my variable, instead of the overflow value. Does anybody know a way to catch, and get around these overflow errors?

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Latest Estimate", sSQL)

            Set dbs = CurrentDb
            Set rstAnswer = dbs.OpenRecordset("Latest Estimate")

            If Not (rstAnswer.EOF And rstAnswer.BOF) Then
                rstAnswer.MoveFirst
                Do Until rstAnswer.EOF
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer!BU)
                    xlSheet.Range("BA" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer!Program)
                    xlSheet.Range("BB" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![EIS Date])
                    xlSheet.Range("BC" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Part Count])
                    xlSheet.Range("BD" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Current Actual Cost Index])
                    xlSheet.Range("BE" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![LTA Index ($)])
                    xlSheet.Range("BF" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![LTA Index (part count)])
                    xlSheet.Range("BG" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![LCB Index])
                    xlSheet.Range("BH" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Drawings Released by Need Date])
                    xlSheet.Range("BI" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Total Drawings released vs Needed])
                    xlSheet.Range("BJ" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![% Of Parts With Suppliers Selected])
                    xlSheet.Range("BK" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![% POs placed vs needed])
                    xlSheet.Range("BL" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    'tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![UPPAP Requirement])
                    xlSheet.Range("BM" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Number of parts identified for UPPAP])
                    xlSheet.Range("BN" & CStr(tempRow)).Value = tempString
                    rstAnswer.MoveNext
                    tempRow = tempRow + 1
                Loop

            Else
                MsgBox "There are no records in this recordset"
            End If
            programsAnswer.MoveNext
        Loop
```

I've tried using GoTo's to catch the overflow error and assign the new value to my tempString variable but this did't work, and even if it did, the way I was implementing it would be cumbersome.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you are reading the fields from the recordset? tempString = CStr(rstAnswer!Program)

Comment: Have you tried Str(rstAnswer!BU)?

Comment: yes, specifically on the lines which can possible generate (0/0) as a result. The first to do so is [Drawings Released by Need Date]

Comment: using Str(rstAnswer!BU) gives me a type mismatch error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not aware of using the method CopyFromRecordset  on the range object check it out.  If your recordset only contained the columns you wanted to dump into excel you could massively simplify your code.

```
eg xlSheet.Range("BA"&1).CopyFromRecordset  rstAnswer
```

Here some example code using an ADO recordset but DAO will work too!

```
'
'Example of gathering data from an Access Application
' into excel (but similar for other apps)
'
Private Sub cmdGather_Click()

    'Define Variables
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkbook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim oAdoConnect As Object
    Dim adoRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lngColumn  As Long
    Dim strNewFile As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Always have a way to handle errors
    On Error GoTo Handler

    'Establish your ADO connection
    Set oAdoConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oAdoConnect.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    oAdoConnect.Open = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Inventory.mdb"

    'Create the SQL statement
    strSQL = _
        "SELECT Customers.* " & _
        "FROM Customers " & _
        "WHERE (((Customers.ContactName) Like ""M*""));"

    'Create and open your recordset
    Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    adoRecordset.Open strSQL, oAdoConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    'Create your Excel spreadsheet
    Set xlApp = Application
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    'Add the new Worksheet
    With xlWorkbook

        Set xlSheet = .Worksheets.Add
        xlSheet.Name = "Customers"

        ' Adds field names as column headers
        For lngColumn = 0 To adoRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
            xlSheet.Cells(1, lngColumn + 1).Value = adoRecordset.Fields(lngColumn).Name
        Next

        ' bold headers
        xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlSheet.Cells(1, adoRecordset.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

        ' dump the data from the query
        xlSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset adoRecordset

    End With

    'Close the RecordSet
    adoRecordset.Close

    'Cleanup variables
    Set adoRecordset = Nothing
    Set oAdoConnect = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Handler:
    MsgBox _
        "An Error Occurred!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Error Message: " & vbNewLine & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Error Source: " & Err.Source, vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. on the line (oAdoConnect.Open = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Inventory.mdb") What do I set the final part to, the "Inventory.mdb" string. The name of my access database?

Comment: @Dp  forget the example code for now if you don't understand it.  Simply replace your whole if statement and the code it include with `xlSheet.Range("BA1").CopyFromRecordset  rstAnswer ` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value before you cast it.

```
If rstAnswer.Fields("Drawings Released by Need Date").Value <> "0/0" Then
    tempString = CStr(rstAnswer!Drawings Released by Need Date)
Else
    tempString = "0%"
End If
```

Comment: This seems good, but still gives me an overflow error. Just trying to read the value apparently will cause an overflow. Also I don't think the value in the cell is literally "0/0", but is first evaluated. I assume it has something like "#DIV/0" in it, but I don't know of any way to check.

Comment: Maybe whatever is in the recordset doesn't need cast. Try changing the assignment inside the if statement.  tempString = rstAnswer.Fields("Drawings Released by Need Date").Value or tempString = str(rstAnswer.Fields("Drawings Released by Need Date").Value)

Comment: Also, you could try changing Dim tempString As Variant

Comment: Thanks for the help Matt, but I tried getting rid of the Cstr() cast and using a variant, still giving the same error.

Comment: We need to know what is in the "Drawings Released by Need Date" field of the DB. Are the null maybe?

Comment: the "Drawings Released by Need Date" field is one line of an output from a query involving a division. I don't know how to access this value without getting the overflow error, so I don't know what it may contain.

Comment: What will it do if you do a msgbox(rstAnswer.Fields("Drawings Released by Need Date").Value) right before the line tempString = CStr(rstAnswer![Drawings Released by Need Date])

Comment: What does your locals window show? Can you see what the recordset shows for that field as far as type?

Comment: Running MsgBox TypeName(rstAnswer![Drawings Released by Need Date]) gives me "Field2" as a type

Comment: I don't know why it would make a difference but try declaring a field and set the that=thefield  Dim f As Field then do something like f.Value = rstAnswer![Drawings Released by Need Date] See if that takes it and then try to work with that.